# Coil displaying white image when reading from file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use `Coil` in my jetpack compose project to display a image chosen from the users files. The below is the code for displaying the image :

```
Card(
    shape = CircleShape,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(8.dp)
        .size(100.dp)
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
) {
    AsyncImage(
        model = profileImageUri,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize(),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_profile)
   )
}
```

Here `profileImageUri` is stored locally using a `datastore` (i.e. `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A3575`). [Image that Coil loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K9ts.jpg)
It is white and does not show anything.

However after loading a new image using the `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` :

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    uri?.let { profileImageUri = it.toString() }
}
```

Coil loads the images correctly and the `Card` on other screens also load the image correctly too. The white image happens after closing the app and opening it again. Is there a permission I am not calling, since I am already trying to call `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72036383/3585796) answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72036383/3585796

Comment: Looks like the right answer, thanks for the help!